# How do you properly use the /v command line argument in Nodes child_process.execFile?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, installation

I am trying to silently install an application via a child process in node but I cant seem to get the /v command line argument to work correctly.

So far I have tried

```
const child = execFile("test.exe", ['/S', '/v"/qn INSTALLDIR="C:\testInstall\""'], (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
                __this.log.error(error, {ErrorId: Logging.ID.ERR_UPDATE_INSTALL});
            }

        });
```

Considering that `"test.exe" /S /v"/qn INSTALLDIR="C:\testInstall\""` works from the command line, I expected the code to work. Instead it seems to do nothing, it doesn't return an error but also doesn't run the installer. A msiexec.exe appears but never does anything. If I remove the second argument and just leave the /S it works as expected aside form obviously only installing to the default directory.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: According to my knowledge, execFile will not spawn a new shell or cmdprompt. So there is some limitations for executing commands. Can you try the same thing with exec?

Comment: @PrinceDevadoss That was it man! Thanks!